# PyQt: mouseReleaseEvent if mousePressEvent happened at different widget

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qwidget

I want to implement a drag and drop functionality between two custom widgets. My understanding from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453308/how-to-drag-and-drop-custom-widgets) is that I cannot use the built-in drag and drop functionality that e.g. buttons would provide, but that I need to implement `mouseReleaseEvent` and `mousePressEvent` handlers manually.

My specific goal is as follows: I have widgets of type `Widget1` and `Widget2`, and I want that when `Widget1` is dragged onto `Widget2`, a certain action is performed. I therefore implemented the `mousePressEvent` of `Widget1` and the `mouseReleaseEvent` of `Widget2`.

```
class Widget1(QWidget):
   ...
   def mousePressEvent(self, event):
      print("Press")

class Widget2(QWidget):
   ...
   def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
      print("Release")
```

While `"Press"` is printed whenever I click on `Widget1`, `"Release"` is printed only after *clicking* on `Widget2`. That is, the release event is called for the same item that was *clicked*. How do I execute an action for the widget that the mouse was over at *release*?

Comment: Once a `mousePressEvent` is captured (and not ignored) by a widget, it takes control of any other mouse event. You have to implement the `mouseReleaseEvent` event on the widget that originates the press event, or, otherwise, use an event filter.

Comment: @musicamante how would I figure out on which widget the mouse is released? Would I have to compute this from the pixel position? Is there a simpler way? Would an event filter help me with that? How?

Comment: You can use [`childAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#childAt-1) on the top level window of the widget (via `window()`).

Comment: @musicamante like self.childAt(event.pos()))  given event an mousepressevent ??

Comment: @pippo1980 Yes, but not with the event `pos`: you must use the `globalPos()` with `mapFromGlobal()` on the top level widget.

Comment: @musicamante I am using pos() on a QGroupBox inside a second QMainWindow and seems to do the expected job, I'll post a question about it for other reasons soon, first need to figure out out to return standard mousepressEvent on if else clause when rewriting def mousePressEvent(self, event): to intercept some stuff

Comment: scrap the return part above  def mousePressEvent(self, event) is rewritten for each widget